# SVG Logo pixelated on wordpress website

Tags: website-design, svg, image-quality

I have saved my vector logo as .SVG file from adobe illustrator. But when i upload it on my website it is pixelated. The size of the logo which i want on my logo is (125px by 125px) but i am unable to get a crisp logo on pc screenl. But on mobile it is very crisp.

The image attached is the header of my website.

[image: Website header]

Comment: The logo looks pretty crisp to me. What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is probably in resolution of your screen. change it and then see the logo.

Comment: Wordpress doesn't natively allow the upload of SVGs.  Are you using a third-party plugin or did you edit your functions.php manually to allow uploading SVGs into the WP media library?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress can either be forced to accept **SVG** as a MIME type (undesirable approach - security issues) or a proper plugin can be used which both allows use of **SVG**s and sanitizes them - preventing code injection attacks and so on: one with a good reputation last time I was looking into this was Daryll Doyle’s ***SVG-Sanitizer***.

Short of doing either of these, the SVG is being rasterized on the fly by WordPress upon initial upload, and so is easily pixelated based on in-browser scaling / zooming and other factors.

Also bear in mind that a pure vector **SVG** doesn't really *have* pixel dimensions - you can control the wrapper/container/div in which it's encased, and that can be sized per pixel or percentage, but a *pure* vector **SVG** graphic element is completely resolution independent and freely scalable - hence the S part of ***S***VG.